# MDX Get all Measures with total value

Tags: sql-server, database, mdx

I'm new to MDX and I need to know if there is a MDX-Query, which gets all the measures from all Cubes in a database, with the total count of the data in the measure filtered by the years 2017 and 2018 where SQL Table it would look something like this.

```
CubeName | MeasureName | MeasureCount | DateYear
 Cube 1      Price          200000        2018
 Cube 1      Price          150000        2017
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it one cube at a time:

```
Select [Measures].AllMembers on columns
From [Your Cube Name]
```